# Fontawesome icons, coded within a link, showing up *after* the clickable area

Tags: sass, hyperlink, icons, font-awesome

I have a link on my page that is simply a back arrow. I put the icon directly in my  element, like this:

```
     <a href="../../index.html" target="_blank"><i class="fa-solid fa-arrow-left"></i></a>
```

but on the page it's as if they follow each other. The clickable area is before and above my icon. I tried to replicate [here](https://jsfiddle.net/af0ok4nr/). (not sure the icon shows up properly, but the problem is reproduced)
I saw in another post that adding a target fixes the problem for some, but it didn't for me.
Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: I fixed it by playing with the width of my anchor element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by playing with the width of my anchor element.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer